# Meaning of ‘real as they may be’ in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ‘read as they may be’ meaning in this text? Does it mean ‘as real as they may be’, or ‘which are real’ or ‘which are very real’ or …? This is a confusing structure the meaning of which I couldn’t find.

“Every culture, every society, clings to a myth by which it lives. Ours is the myth of growth. For as long as the economy continues to expand, we feel assured that life is getting better. We believe that we are progressing – not just as individuals but as a society. We convince ourselves that the world tomorrow will be a brighter, shinier place for our children and for their children. When the opposite happens, disillusionment beckons. Collapse threatens our stability. Darkness looms on the horizon. And these demons – **real as they may be** in an economy dependent so entirely on growth – are rendered even more powerful by the loss of faith in our core sustaining narrative. The myth of growth.”

(Excerpt From
Post Growth
Jackson, Tim)

Comment: *And these demons – assuming they are real – are rendered even more powerful by the loss of faith in our core sustaining narrative.*

Answer (score 2):

It means "however real they may be"  (in an economy depending so entirely on growth).

Comment: I.e, the author takes no position on their reality, and dismisses the issue as irrelevant to the point that  the author is attempting to make.